# Find json blocks containing specific string using regexp

Tags: json, regex

I have been spending way too much time on this I think and I need help. I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[{
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "Washington",
    "Details": "bla bla"
}, {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "Illinois",
    "Details": "bla bla"
}]
```

Using regexp, I need to match all blocks within { and } that belong go the City Seattle. I am trying to do a find replace in notepad++. Thanks!

Comment: and how should look the final result?

Comment: I just need to eliminate specific blocks of text within { and } that does not contain a specific city.

Comment: is there any further processing after notepad++? javascript, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ find the following:

**Find what:** `\{\s*"city":\s*"Seattle".+?\}`

**Search Mode; . matches newline:** Checked

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the json and do your mapping programmatic,
but assuming notepad++ supports perl regex this should work:

```
 \{\s*"city": "Seattle",[\s\S]*?},
```